# SQL Recursive CTE Linked Chains

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I've included a simplified dataset for copy/paste. There would be a table of chained components, linked in a specific order. In production, this table would contain hundreds of thousands of chains, each chain containing 5-10 components.

The input will also be chains and I will search the database for any instance where the database chain has the same components in the same order as the input chains. For example, if the database has chain A, B, C, D, E, F, G and I input chains B and A, B, C and D, F, Z; the results will show me:
Input chain B is a match
Input chain A, B, C is a match
Input chain D, F, Z is not a match

Ideally I'd like to be able to input tens of thousands of chains to search against the hundreds of thousands of chains in the database.

I have a solution in VB.Net that grabs all chains from the database that match the first component of each input chain. It then recursively navigates down the database chain until it reaches the end OR it finds that the database chain does not match. It's not elegant and not efficient as it can only be looking at one input chain at a time. I could just as easily write something in SQL that uses a Cursor to the same effect, but again, not very efficient.

I'm trying to find a recursive CTE that would allow me to run the entire query of thousands of inputs at one time.

Here is a simplified dataset:

```
DECLARE @Chains TABLE (ID int, Component varchar(15), ParentID int, DisplayOrder int, ChainID int)
DECLARE @SearchChains TABLE (Component varchar(15), DisplayOrder int, GroupID int)

INSERT INTO @Chains (ID, Component, ParentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (1, 'Head bone', 0, 0, 1)
INSERT INTO @Chains (ID, Component, ParentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (2, 'Neck bone', 1, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO @Chains (ID, Component, ParentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (3, 'Shoulder bone', 2, 2, 1)
INSERT INTO @Chains (ID, Component, ParentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (4, 'Back bone', 3, 3, 1)
INSERT INTO @Chains (ID, Component, ParentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (5, 'Hip bone', 4, 4, 1)
INSERT INTO @Chains (ID, Component, ParentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (6, 'Head bone', 0, 0, 2)
INSERT INTO @Chains (ID, Component, ParentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (7, 'Shoulder bone', 6, 1, 2)

INSERT INTO @SearchChains(Component, DisplayOrder, GroupID) VALUES ('Back bone', 0, 1)
INSERT INTO @SearchChains(Component, DisplayOrder, GroupID) VALUES ('Hip bone', 1, 1)
INSERT INTO @SearchChains(Component, DisplayOrder, GroupID) VALUES ('Leg bone', 2, 1)
INSERT INTO @SearchChains(Component, DisplayOrder, GroupID) VALUES ('Head bone', 0, 2)
INSERT INTO @SearchChains(Component, DisplayOrder, GroupID) VALUES ('Neck bone', 1, 2)
;

WITH cteMatching (ID, Component, ParentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID, RecLevel)
AS
(
SELECT  C.ID, C.Component, C.ParentID, C.DisplayOrder, C.ChainID, 1 as RecLevel
FROM @Chains C
WHERE DisplayOrder = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT C.ID, C.Component, C.ParentID, C.DisplayOrder, C.ChainID, cte.RecLevel + 1
FROM @Chains C
INNER JOIN cteMatching cte ON C.ParentID = cte.ID
)

SELECT SC.Component, SC.DisplayOrder, SC.GroupID, cte.ID, cte.Component, cte.ParentID,
    ISNULL(cte.DisplayOrder, 2147483647) as cteDisplayOrder, cte.ChainID, cte.RecLevel,
    ISNULL((SELECT 1 WHERE SC.Component = cte.Component), 0) as IsMatch
FROM @SearchChains SC
LEFT OUTER JOIN cteMatching cte ON SC.Component = cte.Component
ORDER BY SC.GroupID ASC, cte.ChainID ASC, SC.DisplayOrder ASC, cteDisplayOrder ASC
```

The results are:

```
    Component       DisplayOrder GroupID     ID          Component       ParentID    cteDisplayOrder ChainID     RecLevel    IsMatch
--------------- ------------ ----------- ----------- --------------- ----------- --------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Leg bone        2            1           NULL        NULL            NULL        2147483647      NULL        NULL        0
Back bone       0            1           4           Back bone       3           3               1           4           1
Hip bone        1            1           5           Hip bone        4           4               1           5           1
Head bone       0            2           1           Head bone       0           0               1           1           1
Neck bone       1            2           2           Neck bone       1           1               1           2           1
Head bone       0            2           6           Head bone       0           0               2           1           1
```

The problem here is that SearchChain GroupID 2 (Neck bone-> Head bone) should show a Match with database ChainID 1 (which it does) and it should also show that the Head components match between GroupID 2 and ChainID 2, Neck does not match Shoulder in ChainID 2. But when I comment out ChainID 1 and SearchChain GroupID 1, the results for ChainID 2 and SearchChain GroupID 2 are correct. This is what has me stumped.

The goal is to be able to run multiple SearchChains through multiple database Chains at the same time, and at the moment, my attempts are failing. Does anyone have any suggestions?

-E

Comment: Just to check, if I get this correctly: Both tables lead to independant chains. The chains of your search table are rather short and they are a match, if you find the full chain somewhere within your main-chain. Correct? Is it possible that your chain splits up, crosses or runs in circles or is it a plain chain always?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The Input chains will usually be much shorter in length and the chains will always be linear, start to finish with no loops or crossing.

Comment: I get that this isn't your real data, but the structure is a little weird. That is, it seems like you'd have a Component table, a Chain table, and then you'd search for components regardless of what chain they're in. If the current schema matches your problem space, fair enough; I'm just making observations.

Comment: Hi Elroy, might want to [listen into this :-)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e54m6XOpRgU)

Comment: Shnugo - You found my data source :)

Comment: Elroy, great! This is (almost) exactly what I had in mind... The only tiny bit could be to build the path of your ComponentIDs (`CAST('|' + CAST(co.ID AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))`) which leads to something like `|10|11|12|13|14`. If you need the worded path you may build both. The `LIKE` will perform faster with the much shorter ID path.

Comment: And about *I'm not sure of the etiquette*: In general edits to the question should add information or clearify something but should not change or solve the question. Therefore it would be best to do a rollback with your question and place your code in a new answer. This has two advantages: I can vote this answer up (+10 points for you) and secondly: +10 means you cross the *15-rep-points-border* after which you are allowed to vote on contributions. It would be nice to vote my answer up (+10 for me)

Comment: I've rolled back to the original answer and posted the updated code as my own answer. I already upvoted your answer when you first posted it, but I'm a noob on StackOverflow which means my votes don't count yet. One day, when I grow up, my upvotes will matter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the fact, that the design of your Chains smells (see below) I want to offer you this solution: Both Chains are concatenated to a path and then the search is performed via `LIKE`

```
DECLARE @Chains TABLE (ID int, Component varchar(15), ParentID int, DisplayOrder int, ChainID int)
DECLARE @SearchChains TABLE (Component varchar(15), DisplayOrder int, GroupID int)

INSERT INTO @Chains (ID, Component, ParentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (1, 'Head bone', 0, 0, 1)
INSERT INTO @Chains (ID, Component, ParentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (2, 'Neck bone', 1, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO @Chains (ID, Component, ParentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (3, 'Shoulder bone', 2, 2, 1)
INSERT INTO @Chains (ID, Component, ParentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (4, 'Back bone', 3, 3, 1)
INSERT INTO @Chains (ID, Component, ParentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (5, 'Hip bone', 4, 4, 1)
INSERT INTO @Chains (ID, Component, ParentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (6, 'Head bone', 0, 0, 2)
INSERT INTO @Chains (ID, Component, ParentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (7, 'Shoulder bone', 6, 1, 2)

INSERT INTO @SearchChains(Component, DisplayOrder, GroupID) VALUES ('Back bone', 0, 1)
INSERT INTO @SearchChains(Component, DisplayOrder, GroupID) VALUES ('Hip bone', 1, 1)
INSERT INTO @SearchChains(Component, DisplayOrder, GroupID) VALUES ('Leg bone', 2, 1)
INSERT INTO @SearchChains(Component, DisplayOrder, GroupID) VALUES ('Head bone', 0, 2)
INSERT INTO @SearchChains(Component, DisplayOrder, GroupID) VALUES ('Neck bone', 1, 2);
```

--This is your query

```
WITH recChains AS
(
    SELECT c.ChainID,c.ID,c.ParentID,CAST('|' + c.Component AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ChainAsPath,1 AS Step
    FROM @Chains AS c
    WHERE c.ParentID=0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT nxt.ChainID,nxt.ID,nxt.ParentID,prv.ChainAsPath + '|' + nxt.Component,prv.Step+1
    FROM recChains AS prv
    INNER JOIN @Chains AS nxt ON prv.ChainID=nxt.ChainID AND prv.ID=nxt.ParentID
)
,ChainsPath AS
(
    SELECT ChainID,ChainAsPath
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ChainAsPath
              ,ChainID
              ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ChainID ORDER BY Step DESC) AS StepOrderRev
        FROM recChains
    ) AS tbl
    WHERE StepOrderRev=1
)
,SearchPath AS
(
    SELECT GroupID
          ,(
            SELECT CAST('|' + Component AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
            FROM @SearchChains AS p
            WHERE p.GroupID=sc.GroupID
            FOR XML PATH('')
           ) AS SearchPath
    FROM @SearchChains AS sc
    GROUP BY GroupID
)

SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN ChainAsPath LIKE '%' + SearchPath + '%' THEN 'X' ELSE '' END AS Match 
FROM ChainsPath
CROSS JOIN SearchPath
```

I must admit, that I did not fully understand your expected result, hope this is what you need:

```
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------+-------+
| ChainID | ChainAsPath                                           | GroupID | SearchPath                   | Match |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------+-------+
| 1       | |Head bone|Neck bone|Shoulder bone|Back bone|Hip bone | 1       | |Back bone|Hip bone|Leg bone |       |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------+-------+
| 2       | |Head bone|Shoulder bone                              | 1       | |Back bone|Hip bone|Leg bone |       |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------+-------+
| 1       | |Head bone|Neck bone|Shoulder bone|Back bone|Hip bone | 2       | |Head bone|Neck bone         | X     |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------+-------+
| 2       | |Head bone|Shoulder bone                              | 2       | |Head bone|Neck bone         |       |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------+-------+
```

### Design

The pattern of parentID pointing to another row of the same set (*self-reference*) is clumsy... You choose this for trees and paths and - in general - graphs. **It must be *gap-less*.** A plain chain is much easier configured as a list with a ranking. You might use one column for the display rank and another for the technical chain. Like you do it with your search chains... `ORDER BY` is faster and cleaner (and allows gaps), than a recursive CTE, which is a *hidden RBAR* and therefore rather slow...

### Design 2

I'd advise you not to use the words itself for the path, but rather use a catalog table for your components and build the path from their IDs. This is cleaner, better to maintain and faster.

Comment: Thank you for the potential solution AND the explanation. I always like to know WHY something works. Let me dig into this a little bit and make sure I understand it all. I had assumed that the inline recursive CTE would not be an RBAR, but I admit that set theory is not my area of expertise.

Comment: My early attempts to solve this did not include the ParentID, I only added that in order to try a recursive CTE. I've edited my original question with your solution, with the recursive CTE removed. Is that what you had in mind or do you have more efficient approach?

Answer (score 2):

This is my final solution with a new structure:

```
DECLARE @Chains TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), ComponentID int, DisplayOrder int, ChainID int)
DECLARE @SearchChains TABLE (ComponentID int, DisplayOrder int, GroupID int)
DECLARE @Components TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(10,1), Component varchar(15))

INSERT INTO @Components (Component) VALUES ('Head bone')
INSERT INTO @Components (Component) VALUES ('Neck bone')
INSERT INTO @Components (Component) VALUES ('Shoulder bone')
INSERT INTO @Components (Component) VALUES ('Back bone')
INSERT INTO @Components (Component) VALUES ('Hip bone')
INSERT INTO @Components (Component) VALUES ('Thigh bone')
INSERT INTO @Components (Component) VALUES ('Knee bone')
INSERT INTO @Components (Component) VALUES ('Shin bone')
INSERT INTO @Components (Component) VALUES ('Ankle bone')
INSERT INTO @Components (Component) VALUES ('Heel bone')
INSERT INTO @Components (Component) VALUES ('Foot bone')
INSERT INTO @Components (Component) VALUES ('Toe bone')
INSERT INTO @Components (Component) VALUES ('Leg bone')

INSERT INTO @Chains (ComponentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (10, 0, 1)
INSERT INTO @Chains (ComponentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (11, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO @Chains (ComponentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (12, 2, 1)
INSERT INTO @Chains (ComponentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (13, 3, 1)
INSERT INTO @Chains (ComponentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (14, 4, 1)
INSERT INTO @Chains (ComponentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (10, 0, 2)
INSERT INTO @Chains (ComponentID, DisplayOrder, ChainID) VALUES (12, 1, 2)

INSERT INTO @SearchChains(ComponentID, DisplayOrder, GroupID) VALUES (13, 0, 1)
INSERT INTO @SearchChains(ComponentID, DisplayOrder, GroupID) VALUES (14, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO @SearchChains(ComponentID, DisplayOrder, GroupID) VALUES (22, 2, 1)
INSERT INTO @SearchChains(ComponentID, DisplayOrder, GroupID) VALUES (10, 0, 2)
INSERT INTO @SearchChains(ComponentID, DisplayOrder, GroupID) VALUES (11, 1, 2)
INSERT INTO @SearchChains(ComponentID, DisplayOrder, GroupID) VALUES (10, 0, 3)
;

WITH ChainPath AS
(
    SELECT ChainID
        ,(
            SELECT '|' + CAST(co.ID AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
            FROM @Chains AS ch
                INNER JOIN @Components co ON ch.ComponentID = co.ID
            WHERE ch.ChainID = cc.ChainID
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) as ChainPath
    FROM @Chains cc
    GROUP BY ChainID
)
,SearchPath AS
(
    SELECT GroupID
          ,(
            SELECT '|' + CAST(c.ID AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
            FROM @SearchChains AS p
                INNER JOIN @Components c ON p.ComponentID = c.ID
            WHERE p.GroupID=sc.GroupID
            FOR XML PATH('')
           ) AS SearchPath
    FROM @SearchChains AS sc
    GROUP BY GroupID
)


SELECT SP.*, CP.*
FROM ChainPath CP
INNER JOIN SearchPath SP ON CP.ChainPath + '|' LIKE '%' + SP.SearchPath + '|' + '%'
```

Comment: I went ahead and changed my solution to reflect the ID's in the search Path. First, as you said, it should be faster. Second, using the ID's will prevent any issues with a pipe character | being used in the Component name. Data validation is good. Not ever allowing user input to appear in SQL code is better.

Also, I added a trailing | to the final search query. Without it, there is the potential for a bad match. Searching |12|34 would potentially match |12|345. Now |12|34| will not match |12|345|.